# Pandas - Faster way to split by last \ and use part of string in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I created a while loop which seperates the file path from the file/exe column of a pandas dataframe and puts the file path into a new column.

```
#Count rows
rows = len(DF1)
#While loop to grab file path - new column
index = 0
while (index < rows):
  DF1['ParentPath'].iloc[index] = DF1['ParentPathExe'].iloc[index].rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
  DF1['ChildPath'].iloc[index] = DF1['ChildPathExe'].iloc[index].rsplit('\\', 1)[0]
  index = index + 1
```

This works but it is extremely slow on 6.5 million rows.
The file/exe column is filled with items like the following:

```
C:\Windows\System32\conhost.exe
C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
C:\Windows\System32\raserver\raserver.exe
```

Some of the file paths have 3 "\" some have 4,5,6 "\" etc.

I use the following code to strip off the .exe and this is extremely fast.

```
#Strip out EXE into new column
DF1['ParentExe'] = DF1['ParentPathExe'].str.split('\\').str[-1]
DF1['ChildExe'] = DF1['ChildPathExe'].str.split('\\').str[-1]
```

Is there a way to avoid the while look and do something like I did for the .exe's?

Comment: Iterating over DataFrames is usually unnecessary and contrary to the whole concept of relational data, and is slow. You can apply any function to a whole column (i.e. Series) using the `apply` method, check it out.

Comment: just from looking on it: `pathlib`is excellent for stripping paths from files. You could just hook it into an apply call. It might be fast enough. You could even think of some kind of extension array (which is a new API in pandas to implement a path object)

Comment: @Denziloe apply is just a thinly masked for loop. It is *not* vectorized.  In fact, it can easily be beaten by list comprehensions nearly all the time

Comment: Something like this?  DF1['ParentPath'] = DF1['ParentPathExe'].apply(rsplit('\\', 1))

Comment: @user3483203 I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: @sectechguy Not quite, rsplit isn't defined. But never mind that anyway -- I've just checked and Series.str.rsplit already exists anyway. Why not just use that?

Comment: I got Series.str.rsplit to work in my example above for capturing the .exe.  I just can't get it to work for the full file path excluding the exe. @Denziloe

Comment: This seems to work DF1['val'].str.split('\\').str[0:-1]  but if there is an int in the filepath is throws an error

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of your suggestions.  I went with rsplit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-wrote both the Child and Parent lines to split into file path and .exe using rsplit:

```
#Split ParentPathExe into path and exe columns
Parent = DF1['ParentPathExe'].str.rsplit("\\", n=1, expand=True)
#Rename columns
Parent.columns = ['ParentPath', 'ParentExe']

    ParentPath                                  ParentExe
0   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs
2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs
3   C:\Windows\System32 svchost.exe
4   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  WrlsAutoSW.exs

#Split ChildPathExe into path and exe columns
Child = DF1['ChildPathExe'].str.rsplit("\\", n=1, expand=True)
#Rename columns
Child.columns = ['ChildPath', 'ChildExe']

    ChildPath   ChildExe
0   C:\Windows\System32 conhost.exe
1   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
2   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
3   C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared...   OfficeC2RClient.exe
4   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
5   C:\Program Files (x86)\Wireless AutoSwitch  wrlssw.exe
```

Then merged the two dataframes together:

```
DF1 = pd.concat([Parent, Child], axis = 1)
```